# Show isomorphism of two groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

> Prove isomorphism of groups $\langle G, + , {}^{-1}\rangle$ and $\langle G, *,{}^{-1}\rangle$, where $a*b=b+a$
>    $\forall a,b \in G$

I'm barely starting to study abstract algebra.

So how do I show isomorphism? I think that I should show a homomorphism somehow, but I don't know how.

Any thoughts/ideas would be really appreciated!

Comment: @Couchy311 The identity doesn't work here (if G nonabelian).

Comment: @ChrisCuster Oops, I misread. Now deleted.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Define $f(a)=a^{-1}$ and prove that it is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi (g)=g^{-1}\,,\forall g\in G$.

$\phi$ is a homomorphism:   $\phi (g*h)=(g*h)^{-1}=h^{-1}*g^{-1}=g^{-1}+h^{-1}=\phi(g)+\phi(h)$.

The kernel of $\phi$ is trivial:  $\phi(g)=e\implies g^{-1}=e\implies g=e$.

$\phi$ is surjective:  $\forall g\in G,\phi(g^{-1})=g$.

Thus $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Could you explain why we need kernel there?

Comment: Sure.  It's one way to show injectivity.